# Initializing a member variable STL vector through a class constructor

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following code which seems to work:

```
class MapCell
{
    public:
    int x, y, z;
};

void Test3DVector(int size_x, int size_y, int size_z)
{
    vector< vector< vector<MapCell> > > m(size_x, vector<vector<MapCell>>(size_y, vector<MapCell>(size_z)));

    for (int x = 0; x < size_x; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size_y; ++y)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < size_z; ++z)
            {
                m[x][y][z].x = x;
                m[x][y][z].y = y;
                m[x][y][z].z = z;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a class that has the 3D vector as a member variable, with the dimensions set in the constructor, like so:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        vector< vector< vector<MapCell>>> m;    // I'm not sure how to write this
    MyClass::MyClass(int size_x, int size_y, int size_z)
    {
        // Do the same initialization as Test3DVector did.

    }
 };
```

So that I can do something like this:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
   MyClass grid(5, 5, 5);
   cout << grid->m[1][3][2].x << grid->m[1][3][2].y << grid->m[1][3][2].z << endl;
   // Should output 132
}
```

What is the best way to do this? When the vectors become very large are there any common mistakes that I should avoid to get the best speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**updated** with a variadic version

### 1. Simple, explicit code

```
class MyClass {
public:
    vector<vector<vector<MapCell>>> m;
    MyClass(int size_x, int size_y, int size_z)
        : m(size_x,
            vector<vector<MapCell> >(
                size_y,
                vector<MapCell>(size_z)
            )
           ) {
    }
};
```

### 2. With a helper

```
class MyClass {
    vector<vector<vector<MapCell>>> m;
public:
    MyClass(int size_x, int size_y, int size_z)
        : m(Dim(size_z, Dim(size_y, Dim(size_x, MapCell())))) {
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    static std::vector<T> Dim(size_t n, T&& v) {
        return std::vector<T>(n, std::move(v));
    }
};
```

### 3. With a variadic helper

Because [*variadics are funadic!*](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Variadic-Templates-are-Funadic) here is a version using variadics to make things ... prettier (depending on taste):

```
struct MyClass
{
    vector<vector<vector<MapCell>>> m;
    MyClass(int size_x, int size_y, int size_z)
        : m(vec_matrix(MapCell(), size_z, size_y, size_x))
    { }

private:
    template <typename T> static std::vector<T> vec_matrix(T v, size_t n) {
        return { n, std::move(v) };
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Dim> static auto vec_matrix(T v, size_t n, Dim... other)
        -> std::vector<decltype(vec_matrix(v, other...))> {
        return { n, vec_matrix(v, other...) };
    }
};
```

**PS**. I have slightly edited the code to be more standards-compliant. There is a subtle issue with templates and [*trailing-return-type*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax) that refers to an overload of the same name.
For a nice breakdown of the issue here, see [this discussion bookmark in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/latereturntype-and-variadics)

In case your compiler doesn't believe it should work, see it **[live on gcc 4.7.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/d72e6a6134dbfe5aebbc32bd06a685c0)**. *It uses boost only to format the output:*

```
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
-------
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
```

---

Full code to avoid link-rot on SO:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp> // for debug output only

using namespace std;

struct MapCell 
{
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, MapCell const&)
    { return os << "."; }
};

struct MyClass
{
    vector<vector<vector<MapCell>>> m;
    MyClass(int size_x, int size_y, int size_z)
        : m(vec_matrix(MapCell(), size_z, size_y, size_x))
    { }

private:
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // variadics are funadic!
   template <typename T> static std::vector<T> vec_matrix(T v, size_t n) 
   {
      return { n, std::move(v) };
   }

   template <typename T, typename... Dim> static auto vec_matrix(T v, size_t n, Dim... other)
      -> std::vector<decltype(vec_matrix(v, other...))> 
   {
      return { n, vec_matrix(v, other...) };
   }
   ////////////
};

int main()
{
    MyClass a(4,5,2);

    using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
    std::cout 
        << format(stream % ' ' % eol % "\n-------\n", a.m) 
        << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: **Updated** Variadic version added for fun and glory :)

Comment: **PS**. I have slightly edited the code to be more standards-compliant. There is a subtle issue with templates and [_trailing-return-type_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax) that refers to an overload of the same name.
For a nice breakdown of the issue here, see [this discussion bookmark in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/latereturntype-and-variadics)